# Recommended cheap and fast SDHC USB card reader?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, accessories, usb, card-reader

I need a few cheap and fast USB card readers, mainly for SD (16GB cards), CF support would also be nice.

Any pro/cons about:

- [Vivanco](http://www.vivanco.de/cgi-bin/vivanco/en_US/productDetail.html?catId=496&showItems=1&pageNo=1&pageSize=10&productId=7753&todo=add)
- [Transcend P7](http://www.transcendusa.com/Products/ModDetail.asp?ModNo=269&SpNo=-100&LangNo=0)
- [Lexar Professional Dual-Slot USB Reader](http://store.lexar.com/?category=22&subcategory=8&productid=RW035-001)
- [SanDisk ImageMate](http://www.sandisk.com/products/readers-accessories/sandisk-imagemate-all-in-one-usb-20-reader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a cheap ebay one (couple bucks?) that had 150x written on it.  It read/writes my SanDisk Extreme III at 20 MB/s, even when the auction says it is much slower.  Originally found out from a slickdeals thread where they did speed tests.  Still going strong after a year.

The non 150x one I got is much slower at around 3 MB/s.

Comment: Model/product number?

Comment: Theres an endless number on ebay, search for SDHC USB.  Here is one:

http://cgi.ebay.com/SD-SDHC-MEMORY-CARD-READER-USB-1GB-2GB-4GB-8GB-/390200464515?pt=PCC_Drives_Storage_Internal#ht_2234wt_1138

Oh, they take several weeks to get in.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a really cheap (about $5 iirc) [SIIG usb card reader](http://www.siig.com/ViewProduct.aspx?pn=JU-MR0512-S1) at Frys Electronics.  The MSRP is $17, but it was much cheaper in store.  It works really well with sdhc cards.

Normally I get these types of items at [Newegg.com, they have a great selection and good reviews.](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007958%20600031471%20600021094&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&Order=RATING&PageSize=20)

Answer (score 0):

[Trust 61-in-1 USB2 Card Reader CR-1610p](http://www.trust.com/products/product.aspx?artnr=15093) reads with 4.5 MB/s and writes with 3.5 MB/s.

[Transcend Multi-Card Reader P8](http://www.transcendusa.com/Products/ModDetail.asp?ModNo=220) (~15 USD) reads with 18.5 MB/s and writes with 10 MB/s.

Both readers were tested with a 2 GB Kingston microSD card, in "optimize for performance" mode.